# How to expand the the drop down menu of a button to the left side?

Tags: html, css

i am builduing a dropdown menu and want that the opening menu expands to the left side and not to the right side of the above button. Currently the drop down menu opens to the right and i dont see a way to change it. I created the following picture to make it more clear.

[image]

```css
.button-container {
position: relative;
/*text-align: center;*/
padding: 0;
border-radius:50%; 
overflow:hidden;
width: 15%;
/*float: center;*/
}

.button-container img{width:100%; height:auto; display:block}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  font-weight: 600; /*Semi-Bold = 600*/ /*Bold = 700*/
  font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color:#666666;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  right: 4px;
  left: auto;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    color:#F16852;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
        <div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="button-container">
                    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/300/300"/>
                </div> 
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks a lot. I am happy for any clarification.

Comment: add `margin-left: auto;`  to `.button-container` and `right: 0;` to `.dropdown-content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dropdown is already positioned absolutely relative to the parent `.button-container`, you can expand from the right side by just adding

```
.dropdown-content
{
    right: 0;
}
```

I also added a couple changes to move your icon to the right side to match your example image:

```
.button-container
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown
{
    text-align: right;
}

.dropdown-content
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

```css
.button-container {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
/*text-align: center;*/
padding: 0;
border-radius:50%; 
overflow:hidden;
width: 15%;
/*float: center;*/
}

.button-container img{width:100%; height:auto; display:block}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  font-weight: 600; /*Semi-Bold = 600*/ /*Bold = 700*/
  font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color:#666666;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  right: 4px;
  left: auto;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    color:#F16852;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="button-container">
                    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/300/300"/>
                </div> 
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current code setup, you can try the below code. I have used some `flexbox` properties with other small changes to meet your requirements.

**CODEPEN LINK:**  https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/ZEBExQV

**FULL WORKING CODE:**

```css
    .button-container {
    position: relative;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
      display:flex; /*Code Added */
      justify-content:flex-end;
     margin-left:auto;
    /*float: center;*/
      width:160px;
    }

    .button-container img{width:50px; height:50px; display:block; border-radius:50%} /* Code changed */


    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-content a {
      font-weight: 600; /*Semi-Bold = 600*/ /*Bold = 700*/
      font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      color:#666666;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      right: 4px;
      left: auto;
    }

    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        color:#F16852;}

    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }

    /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
```

```html
 <div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="button-container">
                        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/300/300"/>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```